# Looping logic using 2 lists

Tags: loops

I have an interesting problem and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the loop logic to get what I need. Unfortunately the language I am developing in does not have arrays implemented. This means I need to use Foreach and/or While loops to accomplish this.

**List 1: Samples**
**Format:** SampleName^NumOfCores

**List 2: Sizes**
**Format:** SizeName^Size

Each size name repeats per sample up to an unknown number.

For example if the object contains 2 samples with 1 core each:
Size1^1|Size1^3|Size2^1|Size2^3|Size3^1|Size3^3

If there is more than 1 core, they will follow in sequence up to the maximum possible cores for that sample.

For example, if the first sample has 2 cores and the second sample has 1 core.
Size1^1|Size1^3|Size2^1|Size2^3|Size3^1|Size3^3|Size4^1|Size4^|Size5^1|Size5^|Size6^1|Size6^

For each sample, I need to associate 3 sizes to each core. 
CoreDimensions = NxNxN

Given the example lists below, the output should be:

- Sample1-Core1:1x1x1
- Sample1-Core2:2x2x2
- Sample2-Core1:3x3x3

**Example Lists:**

**Samples:**
Sample1^2|Sample2^1

**Sizes:**
Size_1^1|Size_1^3|Size_2^1|Size_2^3|Size_3^1|Size_3^3|Size_4^2|Size_4^|Size_5^2|Size_5^|Size_6^2|Size_6^|Size_7^|Size_7^|Size_8^|Size_8^|Size_9^|Size_9^|Size_10^|Size_10^|Size_11^|Size_11^|Size_12^|Size_12^|Size_13^|Size_13^|Size_14^|Size_14^|Size_15^|Size_15^

Per Soren's suggestion here is the same list, but in a JSON object format.

```
[{"SizeName": "Sample1","NumberOfCores": "2"},{"SizeName": "Sample2","NumberOfCores": "1"}]

[{"SizeName":"Size_1","SizeValue":"1"},{"SizeName":"Size_1","SizeValue":"3"},{"SizeName":"Size_2","SizeValue":"1"},{"SizeName":"Size_2","SizeValue":"3"},{"SizeName":"Size_3","SizeValue":"1"},{"SizeName":"Size_3","SizeValue":"3"},{"SizeName":"Size_4","SizeValue":"2"},{"SizeName":"Size_4","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_5","SizeValue":"2"},{"SizeName":"Size_5","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_6","SizeValue":"2"},{"SizeName":"Size_6","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_7","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_7","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_8","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_8","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_9","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_9","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_10","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_10","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_11","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_11","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_12","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_12","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_13","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_13","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_14","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_14","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_15","SizeValue":""},{"SizeName":"Size_15","SizeValue":""}]
```

The relationship is fairly simple to understand. Perhaps explaining it a different way will help.

For every Sample, there are N number of Cores.
Each Core has a set of 3 Dimension attributes (SizeValue). For simplicity's sake, let's say they are Length, Height, and Width. So each Core should have LxHxW.

We can assume that for every sample, there will be a new iteration of Size values. However, the cores do not start a new iteration. They are in a set order.

Logically, the sizes would be displayed like this:

```
[{"Name": "Length", "Value":"1"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"1"}]
```

Multiple Cores for a single sample would look like this:

```
[{"Name": "Length", "Value":"1"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"1"},{"Name": "Length", "Value":"2"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"2"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"2"}]
```

However, when you introduce multiple samples into the mix we end up with this:

```
[{"Name": "Length", "Value":"1"},{"Name": "Length", "Value":"2"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"2"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"2"}]
```

And when you have multiple cores with multiple samples:

```
[{"Name": "Length", "Value":"1"},{"Name": "Length", "Value":"2"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"2"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"1"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"2"},{"Name": "Length", "Value":"3"},{"Name": "Length", "Value":"4"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"3"},{"Name":"Height","Value":"4"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"3"},{"Name":"Width","Value":"4"}]
```

In this case, the Cores with LxWxH values of 1 and 3 belong to the First sample and values of 2 and 4 belong to the second sample.

So when I'm done, I'd end up with something like this:

- Sample 1, Core 1 = 1x1x1
- Sample 1, Core 2 = 3x3x3
- Sample 2, Core 1 = 2x2x2
- Sample 3, Core 2 = 4x4x4

Comment: How are your two lists related? Do you think you could use a more common notation to show what your lists contain? Even if you cannot use arrays in your problem space it might help **visualizing** your data if you can provide it e.g. as JavaScript arrays. It will be easier for others to help if you can clarify a bit what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: I edited the post and added a bit more detail. Hopefully it helps.